# get-eventlog returns different results each run

Tags: powershell

I have a function that runs the directory sync tool (for azure AD) on a remote server.
the problem starts with the cmdlet that suppose to return the time the sync started.

It first runs `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta` on the remote server (using `Invoke-Command`). After that it runs this code to get the newest event (using specific parameters):

`$Event = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -ComputerName $ComputerName -Newest 1000 | Where-Object {$_.Source -eq "Directory Synchronization" -and $_.Message -match "Scheduler::StartSyncCycle : Started sync cycle."} |Sort-Object Time |Select-Object -First 1`

The problem starts with the `if` statement that follows

`if ($Event) {Write-Output "Started sync cycle at" $Event.TimeGenerated} else {Write-Output "Sync did not start"}`

The result of that `if` is "Started sync cycle at " (with an empty space after the "at") meaning it cant grab the `$Event.TimeGenerated`. When doing `Write-Host $Event` it shows `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry` and the weird thing is that other times the result of the `if` statement shows the correct info like "Started sync cycle at Wednesday, February 17, 2021 3:27:16 PM".

Can anyone please help me figure this out? What can cause it to show a different result on each run?
Or better yet, what is this `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry` object it sometimes returns?

I have a feeling Im missing something dumb... :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be sorting on `TimeGenerated` instead of `Time`?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my comment below, the `sort` was indeed incorrect and thus was ignored. But it turns out the default way it was sorted was the actual way I needed it to be so, for the cmdlet to ignore the `sort` actually produced the correct result and that's why I didn't see it as a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple bugs. The core one is here:

```
Sort-Object Time | Select-Object -First 1
```

First, while the output for `Get-EvenLog` shows a column named `Time`, there is no property actually named `Time`. You can see this with `Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest 1 | Format-List -Property *`. There are two properties you might want: `TimeGenerated` and `TimeWritten`. Offhand, I'm not sure which `Time` represents since the events I see have the same value for each.

Second, the default order for sorting a datetime is *ascending*. That means this code gets the *oldest* event in the newest 1000 events. That's not what you described the code doing. You should use the `-Descending` switch to get the newest log record.

Next, you should specify the source when you call `Get-EventLog` with the `-Source` parameter since you know the exact source. That will improve performance by making the command do the filtering for you.

Finally, your pattern matching here contains special regex characters:

```
$_.Message -match "Scheduler::StartSyncCycle : Started sync cycle."
```

If this is a literal string you want to match, you should instead match against:

```
$_.Message -match "Scheduler::StartSyncCycle : Started sync cycle\."
```

So I would write your code like so:

```
$Event = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -ComputerName $ComputerName -Source "Directory Synchronization" -Newest 1000 |
  Where-Object Message -match "Scheduler::StartSyncCycle : Started sync cycle\." |
  Sort-Object -Property TimeGenerated -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is with the `Write-Output` statement because I can't recreate it here. However, I would try your code like so:

```
if ($null -ne $Event) {
    "Started sync at $($Event.TimeGenerated)"
}
else {
    "Sync did not start."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually found the real problem and was going to post it as an answer but I just saw you edited your reply with the answer so I'll give it to you. I also took your suggestions regarding the other bugs and fixed them (although they were bugs that didn't affect the end result so fixing them didn't actually solve the issue). What fixed the issue was `"Started sync at $($Event.TimeGenerated)"` instead of the original `"Started sync cycle at " $Event.TimeGenerated`. Thanks